# How to show/hide a static fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there are a bunch of answers on StackOverflow regard my question but none of them fixed my problem as my Fragments are static.

I have two fragments in my activity. The second one is covering the first one and this is the fragment that will be shown/hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FeedActivity">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/listViewFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:name="com.me.cscomponents.fragFeed.FeedFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gh1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/playerViewFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.me.cscomponents.fragPlayer.PlayerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_player"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gh1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the TV app, both of Fragments are visible side by side. However, in the mobile app, `listViewFragment` is visible by default and `playerViewFragment` displays when an item in `listViewFragment` clicks by the user. When the user clicks on the Back button then this view becomes hidden (and therefore `listViewFragment` becomes visible).

This is my code (but it doesn't work as I expect):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed)

        listFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.listViewFragment) as FeedFragment
        playerFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.playerViewFragment) as PlayerFragment

        val d1: Disposable = listFragment.onClickSubject
            .subscribe {
                showOrHidePlayerFragment(true)
                playerFragment.streamCamera(it.camFeedUrl)
            }
        cd.add(d1)

        showOrHidePlayerFragment(false)
    }

    private fun showOrHidePlayerFragment(isVisible: Boolean) {
        val fm = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        if (isVisible) fm.show(playerFragment) else fm.hide(playerFragment)
        fm.commit()
    }
```

The problem is `playerFragment` is still visible when I launch the activity. So, I have no idea how to fix the issue and what is the cause of the problem.

My current workaround is to surround my `playerFragment` in a `FrameLayout` and make this view visible/invisible. This approach works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think few stuff went wrong with your coding. Try to avoid hard coding fragment like

```
android:name="com.me.cscomponents.fragFeed.FeedFragment"
```

Based on your question i prepared a something for you. I just implemented two button click rather publishing a list. Passed an int (you can pass according to your need.). I tried to follow few best practices. For simplicity i used LinearLayout & RelativeLayout.

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

TestActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FeedFragment.OnItemClickedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, FeedFragment.getInstance(), FeedFragment.TAG).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int position) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, PlayerFragment.getInstance(position), PlayerFragment.TAG).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof FeedFragment) {
            FeedFragment feedFragment = (FeedFragment) fragment;
            feedFragment.setOnButtonClickedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feed 1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feed 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

FeedFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = FeedFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    View view;
    OnItemClickedListener callback;
    Button buttonOne;
    Button buttonTwo;

    public static FeedFragment getInstance(){
        FeedFragment fragment = new FeedFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_fragment, container, false);
        buttonOne = view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        buttonTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.button_two);
        init();
        return view;
    }

    private void init() {


        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback.onButtonClicked(1);
            }
        });

        buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback.onButtonClicked(2);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnButtonClickedListener(OnItemClickedListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickedListener {
        public void onButtonClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

fragment_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/demo_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PlayerFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = PlayerFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    private View view;
    private TextView demoTextView;
    private int position;

    public static PlayerFragment getInstance(int position){
        PlayerFragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getArguments() != null ){
            position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
        demoTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.demo_text_view);
        init();
        return view;
    }

    private void init() {
        demoTextView.setText("Player Fragment, clicked position "+ position);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Anik for your answer. You spent a lot of time and I appreciate it. You mentioned: `Try to avoid hard coding fragment` I do not agree with you as this is a way and there are several samples by Google that this approach has been used. Anyways, after spending a lot of time on this, I decided to put the second Fragment  in a new Activity. It simplifies the work and reduces all of the complexities we face.

Comment: Sure you can use this approach. 

But problem is you cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a FragmentTransaction.

You can only replace a "dynamically added fragment". 

But if your requirement is different and you know for sure that you are not going to replace it (or there is no possibility of this fragment to be replaced near future dynamically at runtime) you can use this approach, but you are sacrificng the scope of dynamically adding/replacing fragment at runtime. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tag `fragment` has an id, the Fragment root view will have that id.

So it will be

`findViewById(R.id.oneFragment).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

By example, if `FragmentOne` use the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <!--Chile Viiews-->
</LinearLayout>
```

And you are using the tag fragment, like this:

```
<fragment
id=oneFragment
name=FragmentOne/>
```

Then that linear layout will end up having `oneFragment` as id. That is how the tag fragment works after the fragment is attached the tag fragment id is assigned to the root view o the fragment. You can read more [here](https://github.com/cutiko/FragmentExperiment/blob/master/README.md).

Another way to do this is to use the fragment manager, here is a one-liner:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment).getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cutiko. However, Fragment is not a View, therefore `findViewById(R.id.oneFragment)` won't work unless you want to say `my_fragment.view = View.GONE`. Even this command doesn't work and it is not a recommended way.

Comment: No, Fragment is not a View, is defined as a class that participated in the host lifecycle and can have a user interface. It does work. Did you try it? I have updated my answer with more details @Hesam